# Not able to run bash script in Jenkins through github

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a repository https://github.com/bizimunda/Jenkins-run-bash-script and in that repository I have a .sh script.

This is my stage code

```
stage('Running script file') {
            steps {
                sh "chmod +x -R ${env.WORKSPACE}/myscript.sh"
                sh "chmod +x ./myscript.sh"
                sh './myscript.sh'
            }

        }
```

And this is the error I get

```
+ chmod +x -R /Users/hamid/.jenkins/workspace/running_bash_script/myscript.sh
chmod: -R: No such file or directory
```

Although my file myscript is already in that folder

[image]

Comment: Read the error carefully: it's trying to find a file or directory named "-R". Possibly you've accidentally pasted some other kind of hyphen there, not a normal ASCII hyphen-minus? Or perhaps `chmod` is fussy about the order of its arguments?

Comment: no luck even updated my code

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `chmod +x -R ${env.WORKSPACE}/myscript.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

According to [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod); `-R` is recursive. Not necessary for one file, but run `chmod --help` to see options for your variant.

Pretty sure it's `chmod -R a+x path/to/filename.txt` or omit the `-R` since it's just a file.